# What is the meaning of $\bar{\nabla}$?

Tags: complex-geometry

In Griffiths and Harris's 'Principles of Algebraic Geometry', the authors use the symbol $\bar{\nabla}$ to prove the Weitzenbock identity. But they never show the definition of the symbol. What is the meaning of this symbol and where can I find a reference? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the passage where it appears?

Comment: the bar would be complex conjugate. The nabla a covariant derivative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which page of G&H did you see $\overline{\nabla}$ without definition ?

p.97 of G&H defines it.

$\overline{\nabla} = \overline{\partial}+A^0$

Comment: Yes, I see the identity. But I thought it should be a property rather than a definition considering the name $\bar{z}$-covariant derivative. Thanks.